# Heroku Error: cannot find app when I want to connect to review app

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, heroku-cli, heroku-api

I am creating and connecting to a Heroku Review App.

I created my app in the UI and have also logged in with heroku on my local.

- When I run `heroku apps` nothing shows up.
- When I run `heroku apps --all` or `heroku apps --team (team-name)` I get all the list of apps in that team.org.
- Now I am trying to run this command:

`cat envvars.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs heroku config:set -a (app-name)`

but it gives me the error:

```
Setting --team, ENV_VAR1, ENV_VAR2, ENV_VAR2 and restarting ⬢ (app-name) ... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that app.
```

- I also tried running with the --team like: `cat envvars.txt | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs heroku config:set -a (app-name) --team=(team-name)`

but it gives me same error.

Now I dont know how to fix this error at all.

Comment: Are you sure you are logging into the correct account?  I have a couple of accounts and sometimes when it goes to authenticate it can choose the wrong one.  I also assume when you run heroku login it is completing the login proccess?

Comment: @ScottMilella yes I am logged into the correct and ONLY account I have on Heroku. Plus, as I mentioned I can run the command with the "heroku apps --all" so it means I am logged in -- it only fails on the second command